# ERROR: CCurlFile::FillBuffer - Failed: HTTP response code said error(22) xbmc

Tags: .htaccess, curl, xbmc

I'm trying to host and distribute xbmc addon on my site. I've made a repository which points to the directory where the addon zip file is. At the same folder I have an xml which describes the addon and so the addon name and description are being recognized by xbmc.
However when trying to install the addon it shows 0% downloading progress and then the progress disappears - resulting in the following error inside xbmc.log file:

```
ERROR: CCurlFile::FillBuffer - Failed: HTTP response code said error(22)
```

according to curl errors page, this happens when -

> CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR (22)
>
> This is returned if CURLOPT_FAILONERROR is set TRUE and the HTTP
>   server returns an error code that is >= 400.

by that I assume the error may be caused by a misconfigured access permissions (perhaps I need to change some htaccess configuration?).
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own eventually. Apparently, the file structure was wrong - I needed to follow the file structure as mentioned in section 4.3 [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on_repositories) in order for it to work